# Слежка за запросами MySql

Tags: запрос, mysql

Как следить, какие запросы выполняет MySql и от каких именно запросов долго загружается сайт? На сервере FreeBSD.

Comment: Как вариант написать прослойку между сайтом и MySql которая будет вести лог запросов...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно типа, "онлайн" режиме смотреть [tail-ом](http://rtfm.co.ua/mysql-vklyuchaem-logi/).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно стартовать демон mysqld с параметром **--log[=file_name].**

Но в этом случае будут писаться все запросы и не будет понятно, какой из них занимает много времени.

Можете добавить в my.cnf что-то вроде:

```
log-slow-queries=/tmp/log_for_slow_queries.log //место, где будет храниться лог
long_query_time=4 // если запрос превышает указанное количество секунд то он пишется в лог
```

В этом случае будут писаться в лог только те запросы, которые превышают указанное в **long_query_time** время.

Так же посмотрите вот [эту](http://habrahabr.ru/post/31072/) ссылку.